# InvalidCastException when casting HtmlDocumentCollection to HtmlDocumentCollection in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, exception

every which way i write the following code, i get an `System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'` exception.

```
        HtmlElementCollection Documents = WebBrowser1.Document.All;
```

in the initial code it was part of a `foreach(htmlelement in webbrowser1.document.all)` list, but after refactoring the code to make it work as above, it started giving me this exception.

i tried rewriting it as part of the foreach, but it still does not work, and it really shouldn't have since both codes should be correct, at least for all i know. i cannot see any issues here.

Comment: Your title says "Document" collection, but the question uses "Element" collection. The type of the property *is* `HtmlElementCollection` so that should work correctly. Are you sure the exception happens on that line of code?

Comment: Yep, I messed up the title a bit, but I am sure that's where the error happens. It's really weird, no idea what to do about it

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.

I cannot access controls outside of the main form thread (which is what I was doing).

Fixed it by putting it inside an "Invoke":

```
    public HtmlElementCollection getelem()
    {
        HtmlElementCollection ret = null;

        Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            ret = WebBrowser1.Document.All;
        }));

        return ret ;
    }
```